If $M$ is not a finitely generated module over a left Artin ring $\Lambda$, can we still conclude that $M/\operatorname{rad}(M) \neq 0$?
Let $\Lambda$ be a left Artin ring, and let $M$ be a left module over $\Lambda$. The radical of $M$ is denoted by $\operatorname{rad}(M)$. If $M$ is finitely generated over $\Lambda$, we can conclude that $M/\operatorname{rad}(M) \neq 0$.
Now, the following question arises:
If $M$ is not finitely generated over $\Lambda$, can we still conclude that $M/\operatorname{rad}(M) \neq 0$? Is there a counterexample?

I have concluded that if $M$ is not a finitely generated module over a left Artin ring $\Lambda$, we can still assert that $M/\operatorname{rad}(M) \neq 0$.
This is because a left Artin ring must be a left perfect ring, and a ring $R$ is left perfect if and only if $R/J(R)$ is semisimple and every non-zero left $R$-module contains a maximal submodule.
Therefore, even if $M$ is not finitely generated over a left Artin ring $\Lambda$, we can still conclude that $M/\operatorname{rad}(M) \neq 0$.
At the same time, I would like to thank FShrike and Mrtaurho for correcting my text above.
